# Woocommerce change price in cart when discounted

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I currently have the following products in the database:

[image: Database]

Woocommerce is currently using the "price" field. I want to make it so that if "price_percent" is greater than 0, it would add the "price_percent" discount to the price, and use the new price instead.

Basically when I open the cart, I want to have the discounted price and bill the customer for it (if there is a discount).

Pretty new to WooCommerce/Wordpress so I'm not sure where to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this filter in your theme or plugin to filter the product prices:

```
function filter_woocommerce_price( $price, $product ) { 

    // 1. Set your $price_percent variable
    // 2. Subtract the price_percent from the price $price - $price_percent
    // 3. Set the new $price

    return $price;
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'filter_woocommerce_price', 10, 2 );
```

By the way - you can use `$product->get_id()` within function.